# How do I preempt an actionlib server from a client

Tags: python, ros

I want to stop a server a certain period of time. How can I send a preempt request to a server from a client in ros using python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it! One just has to call `cancel_goal()`:

```
client.cancel_goal()
```